# Selenium: How to select an option from a select menu?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I am writing a Selenium test in PHP using the PHPUnit Selenium extension.

I know how to type something into a text field:

```
$this->type('fieldName', 'value');
```

But how do I select an option from a drop-down menu?

Comment: Little trick: you can always record your test - or part of - using Selenium IDE (Firefox extension) and convert recorded test to PHP using File -> Export test case as ... ->  PHP Selenium RC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand on the other (accurate) answers, you can select based on the label, value, id, or index of the options. From the official reference available at http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html:

> **select(selectLocator, optionLocator)**
>
> Arguments:
>
> - selectLocator - an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
> - optionLocator - an option locator (a label by default)
>
> Select an option from a drop-down using an option locator.
>
> Option locators provide different ways of specifying options of an HTML Select element (e.g. for selecting a specific option, or for asserting that the selected option satisfies a specification). There are several forms of Select Option Locator.
>
> - **label**=*labelPattern*: matches options based on their labels, i.e. the visible text. (This is the default.)
>
>   - label=regexp:^[Oo]ther
> - **value**=*valuePattern*: matches options based on their values.
>
>   - value=other
> - **id**=*id*: matches options based on their ids.
>
>   - id=option1
> - **index**=*index*: matches an option based on its index (offset from zero).
>
>   - index=2
>
> If no option locator prefix is provided, the default behaviour is to match on label.

Comment: could you post the link where you found this?

Answer (score 2):

```
//note that it's the option text not value
$this->select('selectName', 'LabelText');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $this->select("selectFieldIdentifier", "label=Option label");
```