# Selenium: How to verify menu drop down text?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

I'd like to be able to verify the menu has all the proper dropdown menus with out clicking/selecting, just verifying the id/string of each menu item is ok, I saw from here [Selenium: How to select an option from a select menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820112/selenium-how-to-select-an-option-from-a-select-menu/2820933#2820933) how I can select them, but I don't want to select them. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this to verify the element on the page without selecting them, you're xpath would probably vary my example is quite simplified:

HTML:

```
<body>

<select>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Selenium Test Case:

```
public class HomePageTest {

public static HtmlUnitDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
}

@Test
public void initiateTest() throws Exception {
      driver.get("http://localhost/test3.html");
      List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElementsByXPath("//option");
      for (WebElement e : elems)
      {
          System.out.println(e.getText());
      }
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
driver.close();
} }
```