# select a option with selenium2+phpunit

Tags: selenium, select, phpunit

I got a select element that look like this, now I want to open it up and select the option with value t3, so I tried it like this:

```html
<select id="selectMenu">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="t1">test 1</option>
    <option value="t2">test 2</option>
    <option value="t3">test 3</option>
    <option value="t4">test 4</option>
    <option value="t5">test 5</option>
    <option value="t6">test 6</option>
</select>

$this->byId('selectMenu')->click();
sleep(1);
$type = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value(option[value="t3"]'));
$type[0]->click();
```

Now this opens the menu but it does not select the option tag, I thought of using the `select()` instead of `click()` but `select()` is not supported yet (or at least that's the message i get when I try to use the method). I run the following extension PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it's relatively simple.

```
$this->select($this->byId('selectMenu'))->selectOptionByValue('t3');
```

this should select the selectbox's option based on value. Using PHPUnit Selenium 2 v1.3.3

Answer (score 2):

I found I needed to convert the `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element` to a `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element_Select`:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element_Select::fromElement($this->byId('selectMenu'))->selectOptionByValue('t3');
```

Also see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820112/selenium-how-to-select-an-option-from-a-select-menu)

Answer (score 0):

> $this->byId('selectMenu')->selectOptionByValue('t3');

Answer (score 0):

To select using value use

```
      $this->select($this->byName())->selectOptionByValue($value);
```

To select using label use

```
      $this->select($this->byName())->selectOptionByLabel($label);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with

```
$this->select('css=#selectMenu','test 1');
```