# selenium (phpunit) click on drop down link

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, phpunit, mouseover

I want be able click on link from drop down using selenium with phpunit. I don't have any idea how make it happens, can anyone show me example or relevant tutorial, post or anything that can help me figure out.

when I try click on the element without put mouse over the drop down I got this error:

**Element is not currently visible and so may not be interact with command ....**

Thanks.

EDIT:
when I said "drop down" I don't mean regular select. it more like popup 
you can see the example here:
http://investing.com

look how they build the menu I want be able click on 'Technical' -> 'Fibonacci Calculator' for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post out:
[Selenium: How to select an option from a select menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820112/selenium-how-to-select-an-option-from-a-select-menu)

You can find more info about this [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html)

```
select(selectLocator, optionLocator)

Arguments:

    selectLocator - an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
    optionLocator - an option locator (a label by default)

Select an option from a drop-down using an option locator.

Option locators provide different ways of specifying options of an HTML Select element (e.g. for selecting a specific option, or for asserting that the selected option satisfies a specification). There are several forms of Select Option Locator.

    label=labelPattern: matches options based on their labels, i.e. the visible text. (This is the default.)
        label=regexp:^[Oo]ther
    value=valuePattern: matches options based on their values.
        value=other
    id=id: matches options based on their ids.
        id=option1
    index=index: matches an option based on its index (offset from zero).
        index=2

If no option locator prefix is provided, the default behaviour is to match on label.
```

Credits go to Dave Hunt

---

What I use:

```
$search13 = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('id_of_dropdown_field'));
$search13->click(); // Clicking on the dropdownfield

$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->pressKey('ARROW_DOWN'); // Will go down in your dropdown selection )

sleep(1);

$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->pressKey('ENTER'); // Enter for submitting your selection
```

---

EDIT:
http://www.anitpatel.net/2012/02/25/selenium-webdriver-how-to-click-on-a-hidden-link-or-menu/
This one explains it in java but basically what he does is a mouse over/hover and wait.
Then he clicks on the element.
I'm not a java genius but it's an example how to work with it.

You can use the:

```
string mouseOver(string $locator)
```

This simulates a user hovering a mouse over the specified element.
http://docs.tadiavo.com/phpunit/www.phpunit.de/pocket_guide/3.1/en/selenium.html

Comment: thanks, but see my edit I don't need the regular select option.
(if no one will get right answer soon I will mark your answer as a right answer).

Comment: Hmm that's an annoying one, you can click on the menu but then only the side submenu doesn't show in the interface. 
A fast workaround is going to the URL itself.
' http://www.investing.com/forex-tools/fibonacci-calculator ' this one then.

Or you can click on Tools --> shows next interface --> click on 'Trading Calculators '

Comment: the idea is create the test that will be able work with menu changes

Comment: Try to use: string mouseOver(string $locator)
This simulates a user hovering a mouse over the specified element. http://docs.tadiavo.com/phpunit/www.phpunit.de/pocket_guide/3.1/en/selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element is visible using the xpath of the required option value.

`$this->isElementPresent($xpath);
        $this->click($xpath);`

If it is true, then  click() method selects the specified option.